# Is "es geht gut" a natural reply to "wie geht es dir?" or not?

Tags: usage

I have a question to German speakers out there. Someone just texted me saying "Wie geht es dir?" and I replied with "Es geht gut, dankeschön. Und dir?" They didn't see it yet but I figured "Es geht gut." meant  "It goes good." and now I'm confused. So, my question to you guys is, was my reply natural or was it way too far from it?

Comment: The full expression is *Wie geht es dir?* or if you want to be more colloquial, *Wie geht's dir?* or simply *Wie geht's?*. So I think there was a typo in the text you got, though I guess with texts no one cares much.

Comment: As a general comment, you might consider re-editing to use the correct, punctuation, capitalization, and avoid regionalisms like "y'all". Think schoolwork, not text-speak. I'm from the US so I know what you're saying, but this will be seen by people from all over the world with varying degrees of English fluency, so it might help to keep your English as standard as possible. (Of course I'm probably as guilty as anyone of not following this advice, but I do try to follow it.)

Comment: Well, I'm sorry about that. I didn't consider it to be a problem. But honestly, you might be right, although I'm not planning on using the site on a regular basis. It was just a one-time-only kind of thing for me as I don't use the German language that often. Anyway. Thanks for helping me out about the question I asked. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is "unnatural".

> Wie geht's (**dir**)? <-> **Mir** geht's gut.

> Wie läuft'**s**? <-> **Es** läuft gut.

> Wie geht'**s**? <-> **Es** geht gut. ( "Es geht gut" as an answer is very uncommon )

for example in French it is a common phrase:

> Ça va? - Ça va [bien]. --> Wie läuft'**s**? - (**Es**) läuft ([gut]).

(note: the French example isn't a direct translation!)

Comment: I wouldn't say "Wie geht's" is uncommon. It gets about 2 million hits on google, while "Wie läuft's" gets just about 100,000 hits. But there may be a regional preference.

Comment: @mic thanks, i edited my answer. I hope it is now clear what is meant :)

Comment: Ah, I see. But just to mention it: I would answer "Wie geht's?" with "Es geht mir gut" or just "Gut".

Comment: @mic "Mir geht's gut" und "Es geht mir gut" are the same. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Yes, they are effectively the same. I just wanted to say, that I would not answer "Wie geht's" with "Es geht gut" as it's kind of unnatural and thus - as you mentioned - uncommon, but with "Es geht mir gut", or "Mir geht's gut" if you like.

Comment: A possible, not uncommon, answer to „Wie geht's (dir)“ is also „Es geht“, although that has a different meaning, indicating that the answering person isn't unwell per se, but also not happy with the(ir) situation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think it depends very much on the region:
To me it seems that the phrase was put from English to German.
While in English this seems to be the normal greeting, it's less common in German.
So I think your answer was perfectly OK.

Personally I think if some one starts with "Wie geht es ...?", he/she is prepared for a little talk (probably in contrast to the British).
Maybe Germans would try to avoid the "Und dir?", because then you'll have to wait for an answer again.
The usual short German greeting is just ping-pong like.

As said in the comment alternatives would be "Wie geht's, wie steht's?", "Wie läuft's?".
Youth may say "Was geht ab?", "Alles senkrecht?", etc.

Other variants (not inviting for a talk) could be "Hallo!", "Guten Tag/Morgen/Abend/Nacht!", "Servus" (which can also be used as "bye"), "Grüß Gott" (which in my opinion is the short form for "Grüße Dich Gott" (like "may god bless you"), "Habe die Ehre!" (or contracted in Bavaria as "Hawedere!"), or (Bavarian) "Pfüid Di!" (contracted from "Behüte Dich Gott").
All these phrases are responded to one-by-one (usually).